# How do I remove window sill stop block on double-hung vinyl window?

Tags: windows, leak, water-damage, caulk, sill

The vinyl double hung window was installed on my brick house a few years ago. The Screws that hold the replacement windows are drilled in through the bottom of the drain holes with no caulking on the screw heads. Now there are rusted screws and water leaking in home and has molded inside walls. Walls have been torn off and mold remediated...

The question I have is how do I get to the screws to replace and caulk? I don't want to break the bottom sill stop but I don't know exactly how to "pop" it off. I feel like I can pull it up a little bit but don't want to snap this plastic and destroy integrity of window.

I didn't own the house when the install occurred, but no caulk on window screws is a huge workmanship error in my simple mind. I only can reach one of the screws with my hand and screw head is rusted with no caulk in sight.

Any assistance is much appreciated...BTW I have the exact set of windows 5 more times around my house so this may be a much needed process if this is the same procedure used on each set.

Here's the overview of the situation:
[image]

Here is a closeup of a leaky screw:
[image: Rusted leaky screw]

[image]

Here is the window sill stop block
[image: Window sill stop block]

Here is that window after removing the stop block:
[image]

Comment: A few questions: 1) where is that quote from? Did you mean for it to be a quote? 2) Are you sure the screws go through the _drain_ holes, or are those the mounting holes? 3) Are there drain holes to the outside and are they clogged? That could cause the water to back up, rust the screws and leak into the house. I recently had replacement vinyl windows installed. To my knowledge, the screws weren't caulked, just had covers put over them. The water should never get to the mount points in the first place so maybe there's something else going on...

Comment: Also, you've got good close up pics, but it's hard to get an overall context of what's going on. Could you [edit] to include a more distant/overall shot, then follow it with the detail shot so _we_ can form a mental image of what's going on to best help you. Once you've done that and while you're waiting for an answer, take the [tour] and browse the [help] so you can make the most of this site.

Comment: FYI, screws are almost never caulked. If they need to be they're in a bad location or something else was done incorrectly. Chances are they just shouldn't have been installed in the sill at all.

Comment: I like the comments about cleaning the weep holes on the exterior. Should water never reach the inner stop sill?

Comment: I added an additional picture of the whole project. I had mold remediated as my wife’s autoimmune issues began to flare up. So investigation began to find the source of the problem and found the mold and leak under window.

Comment: Ditto what @isherwood said about not caulking screws. If you ever need to remove anything, the caulk will be a _major_ pain! No, water really should never reach _inside_ the pane in any way. Consider taking the garden hose to the outside of the window with someone watching both inside and outside to see if you can see water backing up somewhere and/or leaking through. That will tell you exactly where the ingress is and will let you know what attack vector you need.

Comment: Also, I took the liberty of rotating a couple of images so they were upright. Is that last image from the inside or outside?

Comment: The water hose test showed no immediate leaking but after a while the 6 screws (two on each window) (pictured) began to leak directly on to wood. This was very apparent after blower had dried out wood completely.

Comment: Usually you have to remove the windows to get to the frames, usually I only screw the sides on retrofit windows but one that large I would have screwed the bottom and sealed them. Others may not but a Phillips bit will punch right through a little calking, the weep holes probably never drained as it went in the wall.

Comment: Updated picture: removed the inner sill block from outside window. Found poor caulk job but also lots of water on the stop sill. I plan on cleaning out reinstalling new screws, new caulk, and potentially new weatherstripping so water has a harder time getting down to there to begin with..... any additional comments are welcomed. I appreciate the quick response. I should have used this forum before when I was left scratching my head for weeks!!!!!

Comment: Thank you @freeman got the window all broken down, cleaned up, new screws, new caulk, new weather stripping, cleaned out all weep holes and will put it all back together tomorrow as the plastic pieces are drying now. Thanks again.

Comment: @CaryKoch Glad you got it taken care of! Please copy that comment and paste it in as an answer (maybe add in a few of the other steps you did, too), then give yourself a check mark. That will help others who have run into a similar problem know that this has a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the window all broken down, cleaned up, new screws, new caulk, new weather stripping, cleaned out all weep holes and will put it all back together tomorrow as the plastic pieces are drying now. Thanks again. *Now I wait...Next 10 days is straight rain, so we will see if water leaks on wood or gets in somehow. I will not put the wall back together until I know it is no longer getting wet.

Rusted Corner Screw[image: rusted corner screw]

Poor caulking job allowed water to seep in[image: Poor caulking job allowed water to seep in]

Caulked and sealed new screws[image]

Snapped all stop sills and cleaned up pieces back in[image]

Comment: That was not only a poor job of caulking that screw, but they didn't do a good job of driving it in the first place!

Comment: Please give yourself a check-mark for your answer so others will know that there's a good, workable solution here.